# Travis CI github releases unauthorized

Tags: java, github, deployment, configuration, travis-ci

This is what i did. I build my maven project and trying to deploy it on relevant github repo releases. For that i generated an OAuth2 access token from `Setting>developer>Private Token` giving all the privilages. Once a new key entered to the travis config file. it working fine and deployement occures [Success Build log](https://travis-ci.org/namila007/Maze-Solver/builds/372611769). I can even get the data when i curl using `curl https://api.github.com/?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN` for the fresh token.

When do a new commit/ tires to build again after some times  i get unauthorized access error in travis build;

```
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7/gems/octokit-4.6.2/lib/octokit/response/raise_error.rb:16:in `on_complete': GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3 (Octokit::Unauthorized)
```

.Here is my .travis.yml for my maven build;

```
language: java

cache:
    directories:
     - /home/travis/build/namila007/Maze-Solver/target/

jdk: oraclejdk8

sudo: false # faster builds

script: "mvn install"

before_deploy:
  - "mvn -DskipTests package"

deploy:
  # GitHub - Add zip to release
  - provider: releases
    api_key:
      secure: MY_TOKEN
    file: /home/travis/build/namila007/Maze-Solver/target/Maze-Solver-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      tags:
    all_branches: true
    on_success: always
    on_failure: never
```

whats happening in here?

PS- I found that tokens i generated in my github account, doesnt exist after i do a refresh the page. its not showing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay found the problem i had.

1-**Token Key deletion** - github delete your private token access if it found in a public repo.(prev time i used the private repo,it didnt delete by the github).so dont post the token in public repo.

2- **travis api_key variable** -you can give api_key var as follows;

```
api_key: "GITHUB OAUTH TOKEN"
```

or encrypting ;

```
api_key:
secure: YOUR_API_KEY_ENCRYPTED
```

you can read the [document](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/)

if you are using 1st method keep the key as a travis environment and call it in your script.
ie: if i give KEY , i can use `api_key: ${KEY}` in `.travis.yml` file. if you need encrypt and add it use the 2nd method and read the [encrypt key document](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/)

here i used the first method and it worked. ;)